# parsing string into array (['class': 'navigation', 'id': 'navigation'])

Tags: php, regex, php-5.3

Anyone can suggest an alternative method to parse a string: `(['class': 'navigation', 'id': 'navigation'])`.

I used to use:

```
if(strpos($match[1], '[') === 0)
{
    $render = array();

    foreach(explode(',', substr($match[1], 1, -1)) as $arr)
    {
        $parts  = explode(':', $arr);

        if(count($parts) == 2)
        {
            $render[substr(trim($parts[0]), 1, -1)] = substr(trim($parts[1]), 1, -1);
        }
        else
        {
            $render[]   = substr(trim($parts[0]), 1, -1);
        }
    }

    $args[] = $render;
}
elseif(strpos($match[1], "'") == 0)
{
    $args[] = substr($match[1], 1, -1);
}
```

However, it doesn't take long to understand the drawbacks of this method, e.g. ['title': 'Tom's diary'] would completely fail the code.

It would also nice to be able to identify an erroneous entries and leave them out. At the moment all I do is use: `|{{([^}]+)}}|` to catch all functions, which look like: {{foo}}, {{foo('test', 'best')}} or {{foo(['array': 'bar'])}}. If you have quick solution, I'd appreciate if you share it.

Comment: Will the array always be of this form (`(['x': 'y'])` or might there be some variations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your string's format seems not too far from [JSON](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/JSON) -- even if it doesn't seem to be real JSON *(you are using `[]` instead of `{}`, arround what seems to be an object)*.

Maybe you could change your format, in order to use JSON ?

That would allow you to use the [**`json_encode()`**][2] and [**`json_decode()`**][3] functions.

And more people would be able to work with your data, as you'd be using a standard format.

Comment: This is good idea. @amitchd already suggested that, though. What about the second part of the question. Can anyone see an easy way to ignore malformed function calls?

Answer (score 1):

This is a json string, just use **json_decode** to parse it into an array.

Comment: It is similar to JSON, but is not. Though, this not bad idea. I could indeed change syntax to use JSON-like arrays.

Comment: @Guy switching to JSON syntax would make the most sense - the parsing work is already done for you!